# WCF options for secure internet connectivity

Tags: wcf, security, iis, ssl

The scenario is as follows:

WCF service hosted on the internet. Needs to be highly secure, so I am thinking of security on the transport as well as the message level.

SSL will be used on the IIS, will use certificates on the transport layer.

The message needs to be encrypted and signed. At the message level will using certificates be the best option? The main concern is the identity of the sender and the encryption. Also this service has to be cross platform compatible. Is that even possible with the kind of configuration I am talking about.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't see why not - MS would be doing this in Azure and Live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WCF service hosted on the internet. Needs to be highly secure, so I am
>   thinking of security on the transport as well as the message level.

There is no need to combine Message and Transport level security. Select one and it should be enough.

> At the message level will using certificates be the best option?

Certificate is the most reliable option if building secure solution. You cannot defend against man-in-the-middle attack without valid certificate or something that will do similar to SSL handshake work for you.

> Also this service has to be cross platform compatible.

It will be if you use `wsHttpBinding` binding. `netTcpBinding` is proprietary one and will not work for you.

> Is that even possible with the kind of configuration I am talking about.

Yes

You can start from this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx

Comment: I read in the Improving Web Services Security book that message security should be used when services open to internet. Also that transport layer security was from point to point to and you cannot be sure of the points implementing SSL that may be in between the two communicating services. So security is of the utmost concern to us, there cannot be any loop holes however remote the possibility of a breach may be.

Comment: What is the downside on using both the transport and message security?

Comment: You will not break anything if you use both transport and message level security. Although you will have to do work twice. This double work will add additional costs and affect performance. See that article to decide which method is better for you - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. Will need to weigh the cost and the performance. Probably write some tests for it :)